# Tikz: style for adding prefix to label

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible that an (already existing) style adds a prefix to every label using this style?

So the label in the following example should be `L:label`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzstyle{withPrefix}=[] %add "L:" before every label with this option

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw=black] [label={[withPrefix]label}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**Clarification:**

I use `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}` and want to move the `L{:}` from the label text into the option.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\tikzstyle{future}=[red] %add "L:" before every label with this option
\tikzstyle{now}=[red]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0)    [draw] ["label" future] {a};

\node at (0,-1.5) [draw] ["L{:}label" now] {b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try if the following gives what you like to have: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style args = {#1:#2}{draw, label=#1: L #2}
                    ]
\node [box=above:label] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: or the following: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
lbl/.style args = {#1:#2}{label={[font=\scriptsize]#1:\textcolor{red}{L}~#2}}
                    ]
\node [draw, lbl=below:label] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Zarko I don't want the labels to look any different from normal labels, so something like `{label=#1:L:#2}` should be correct, I guess. But as I use the `quotes` tikzlibrary (removed this by minimizing the example) and actually wanted to write `"label" withPrefix` to produce `L:label` this does not seem to work

Comment: both examples in my comments work.  please, be so kind and show an sketch, what you like that labels look like. your approach (as far as i can understand your *mwe* and description) will not give expected result.

Comment: @Zarko please see my update

Comment: what is more important to you: that you for labels you use `quotes` (which is not intended for labeling of nodes)  or that you have simple standard solution which works?

Comment: I like the short notation from `quotes`, but modifying your comments just a little led my to my solution below (which is short in use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm providing an own answer mainly basing on Zarko's comments.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
future/.style args = {#1}{label={[red]below right:L:#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw,future=label] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: the output]

Answer (score 1):

You could abuse `font` for that. (There is an alternative key, `node font`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\tikzset{future/.style={red,font=L:}, %add "L:" before every label with this option
now/.style={red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0)    [draw] ["label" future] {a};

\node at (0,-1.5) [draw] ["L{:}label" now] {b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and you put label below of node?

Comment: @marmot should `tikzset` always be preferred?

Comment: @Ben This is what one may conclude from [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/121799). I think in your above example it does not really matter because you seem to want the styles to be global. My rationale for weeding `\tikzstyle` out is that there seems to be no advantage using it, and there are cases where using it hurts.

Comment: huh, i lost one word in my comment :-(, correct is : and **how** you put a label below of node?

Comment: @Zarko Was that asked? You could either do `\node at (0,0)    [draw] ["label" {future,below}] {a};` or add it to the definition of the style: `\tikzset{future/.style={red,font=L:,below}}`.

Comment: nice. thank you very much! however i prefer solution which i propose in my second solution ...